# Cannot type curly or square brackets on a Croatian keyboard Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

My usual way of typing curly and square brackets in Ubuntu is (Ctrl + Alt + B, Ctrl + Alt + N) and (Ctrl + Alt + F, Ctrl + Alt + G) respectively.

I have disabled all keyboard shortcuts involving Ctrl + Alt in the keyboard shortcuts menu, but still I cannot type any of these keys.

I am using a Croatian keyboard.

Comment: Do you have an AltGr key, i.e., the right Al key? Then try right Alt+B, etc.

Comment: That actually works, thank you very much. But I would still like to know how can I use the left Alt and Shift because you kind of get used to it after ten years.

Answer (score 0):

The third level shift has a lot of aliases e.g. Alternative Character Key or Alt_Graph key.

This is how you set the key.
Open Settings ➣ Keyboard ➣ Special Character Entry

[image: Settings]

[image: 3rd-lvl_shift]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I cannot seem to find this Special Character Entry on my Ubuntu. On this page I only have the Input Sources tab.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu flavor? If you can open Terminal `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` can do the same.

Comment: Okay I got it. Thank you